# what is the best way to share the web page content in facebook?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-sharer

i am thinking about shearing certain part of my web site only. Like

```
<div id = "">
   <div>
      <p>ABC</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

i am able to share whole page, but i do not want share whole page. My share button code like

```
<div class="fb-share-button"
                        data-href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/111111111/myname"
                        data-layout="button_count" data-size="small"
                        data-mobile-iframe="true">
                        <a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank"
                            href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fsocial%2Fwelcome&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a>
                    </div>
```

Is there a better way to share only part of web sit?
  Thanks.

Comment: Uhhhh, when you share the site on Facebook it actually shares the URL, so you cannot technically share only a subset of the page itself. Unless you have a way of subsetting the content and displaying it at another URL.

Comment: @Terry, thanks, well ok if there is a possibility to make url form div content